# Error : Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have javascript code and got an error **Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined**. Can anyone please help me to solve this? This is my code, and I currently using jQuery 2.1.3.

```
ExpandableTable.prototype.updateInputBoxName=function(){
    $("."+this.cloneClass,this.target).each(function(j,t){
        var n=j+1;
        $("input,textarea",$(t)).each(function(i,v){
            if($(v).attr("name")!=""){
                var newName=$(v).attr("name").replace(/\d+$/,"")+n;
                $(v).attr("name",newName);
            }
        });
    });
    return this
};
ExpandableTable.prototype.updateInputBoxId=function(){
    var t=this;
    $("."+t.cloneClass,this.target).each(function(j,u){
        var n=j+1;
        $("input,textarea",$(u)).each(function(i,v){
            if($(v).attr("id")!=""){
                var newId=$(v).attr("id").replace(/\d+$/,"")+n;
                $(v).removeAttr("id").attr("id",newId);
            }
        });
    });
    return this
};
```

it says i have an error on **.replace**.

Please help me to solve this

Comment: Use the debugger to figure out what is `undefined` and why.

Comment: *As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set.*

Comment: `if($(v).attr("id")!=""){` does not test for undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your if statement needs to check that `$(v).attr("id")` is not undefined

```
  if ($(v).attr("id") != "" && typeof $(v).attr("id") != 'undefined') {
```

Should stop that error.

As MinusFour said `if ($(v).attr("id"))` is less verbose and achieves the same thing.

Comment: You can probably get away with just `if($(v).attr('id'))`.